# Extra argument 'error' in call? But I don't have an 'error' variable at all?

Tags: json, swift, error-handling

I don't have an error variable anywhere, is this a bug in Xcode? I'm very confused on what could be wrong. I've searched all of stack overflow for an answer on this, found nothing. I've tried for several hours to figure out why I'm getting this error for the line of `func parseJson( data: NSData){`

I'm a beginner who studies Swift day and night.

Here is my code below:

```
func parseJson( data: NSData){

do{

    let json: AnyObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])
    if let unwrappedJson: AnyObject = json{

        parseSongs(unwrappedJson)
    }
}catch{


}
}
```

Comment: show your codes on `dataTaskWithURL` I believe you add this method inside your this chunk of code.

Comment: Do not annotate types like `AnyObject` unless the compiler tells you to do

Comment: @vadian so how would I tell the compiler that something is of type anything?

Comment: With a warning or an error. In almost all cases an annotation is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Clean the project and build

If that doesn't word

2. Restart xcode
3. Rewrite the code

Comment: Yes, I've already don't that more than 5 times. I've even restarted my Mac twice.

Comment: @Alex, have you tried to remove that block of code and rewrite it?

Comment: Oh man, you're a genius! Just deleted it and pasted it back in. Works like a charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: Ok you can post it otherwise there is a limit of 90 minutes between each question.

Comment: Yes but stack overflow has prevented me from asking any question for the next 2 days because of my first question that got a lot of hate(I don't know why, I'm just a beginning programmer who try's his best). Can I send it to you through E-mail?